# Counter-jailbreaking

Tags: security, operating-system

This is a curiosity question, and I'm just looking for pointers to learn more; also surely a topic thousands in our community are curious about:

Background: Take the Apple iPhone as an example: Every so often, Apple releases a new version of the OS which is somehow incompatible with previous software meant to "jailbreak" the OS.  Then the jailbreak software authors release a new jailbreak that is compatible with the new OS.  Then Apple releases a new OS version and the cycle repeats.  Most people assume that Apple has an interest in preventing jailbreaking by continually releasing OS updates that invalidate previous jailbreaks.

**Q: In general, how do software developers at a company (say, Apple) go about preventing jailbreaks when they release a new version of the OS? I'm asking about general OS architecture/security and other relevant topics.  And what's the layman's explanation?**

Comment: May be better for http://s.tk/security

Answer (score 2):

A "jailbreak" is a way to run code on iOS which has not been signed and certified by Apple, Inc.

Because iOS is designed from the get-go not to permit this, and no applications which change this property of the OS are certified by Apple, the only way a "jailbreak" can succeed is to exploit a *flaw* in the OS.

So, "preventing jailbreaks" (reactively) is just a matter of removing the most recent flaw which is being exploited. They retrieve the jailbreak, reverse engineer it, discover the vulnerability it exploits, and patch the OS to remove the vulnerability.

In theory, this would mean that eventually Apple would "win" and there would be no bugs left which permit the privilege escalation on which a jailbreak depends. In reality, there is always one more bug.

It's worth noting that there are other ways to break an OS lockdown: for instance, attaching specialized hardware to trigger a manipulable OS malfunction. But these methods are less attractive because they are both more difficult to develop and more demanding to apply than a software-only exploit.

A final way to break Apple's control would be to compromise the key they use to sign applications. This has not happened, although some day it might.